# iOS Masonry, view's size constraint not working if another view's centerX depends on it

Tags: ios, masonry

I'm using Masonry in my project.
At first, I make some constraints to rightToolBar:

```
CGSize rightToolBarSize = CGSizeMake(54, 210);
[self.rightToolBar mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.right.equalTo(self).offset(-10);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.mas_bottom).mas_offset(-20);
    make.size.mas_equalTo(rightToolBarSize);
}];
```

Then another view, avatar:

```
[self.avatar mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(50, 50));
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.rightToolBar.mas_top).with.offset(-10);
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.rightToolBar.mas_centerX);
}];
```

This makes **self.rightToolBar's width becoms 74**, 20 larger than I expected. If I change the avatar's constraints to :

```
[self.avatar mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(50, 50));
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.rightToolBar.mas_top).with.offset(-10);
    make.right.equalTo(self).with.offset(-17); // centerX -> right
}];
```

Now **self.rightToolBar's width is 54**. But this makes no sense, why setting avatar's centerX changes rightToolBar's width?

Comment: One reason to learn constraints, rather than using something like Masonry... it can be tough to figure out what's going on. I'd suggest using `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the elements and constraints... might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove rightToolBar's constraints and remake again

```
[self.rightToolBar removeConstraints:self.constraints.constraints];
[self.rightToolBar mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.right.equalTo(self).offset(-10);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.mas_bottom).mas_offset(-20);
    make.size.mas_equalTo(rightToolBarSize);
}];
```